# My bootstrap website is showing an empty scroll-able blank space on the right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

when it's on pc screen it's no big deal but viewing on mobile it shows this blank space that can be scrolled. I used Creative template from startbootstrap. The original template didn't show it, but only now. I have no idea where it came from and not enough knowledge to go digging.

http://ownscene.com/index-en.html

here's what it looks like on small screens
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndNV1.jpg

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well for me, hope it will resolve your issue.

There is a section

```
<section id="photo" class="bg-dark no-padding">
```

Just inside this there is a  having class="row"

**Add class "container" within this div & remove class "row", it will resolve the issue**

i.e `<div class="container">`

Answer (score 1):

The

```
<div class="navbar-header">
```

is generating the extra width. Looks like it was introduced when you changed the menu options.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the section class="no-padding bg-dark" id="photo" the white space is gone (chrome->inspect element->find section id=photo->right click->delete). So it has to do with this section. I guess you forgot to encapsulate it in a div class='container'.

I hope this helps.